# Xamarin/Mono crashes on Japanese input, Mavericks OSX

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin

I just started using Xamarin with existing windows C# code. Running Mavericks.
It seems to work great until I try to enter Japanese text in a text box.
HIToolbox crashes - looks like it's trying to convert NSNotFound from 64bit MAXINT to the 32bit MAXINT... and of course... you can't do that.

Does anyone have a workaround? or a fix? or a suggestion?
I tried different Japanese input methods, and different fonts in the box, but... same result.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, could you please file it at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com (attaching a project that can be used to reproduce the issue)?

Comment: easy to reproduce...
make a new windows forms app in Visual Studio...
And just add a text box to the form.
Open that solution in Xamarin.MAC and run it... 
works fine until you change the input source to Japanese (hiragana).

But I'll attach that project to the bug report too... 
thanks

Comment: filed #25899
sample source attached.